# HttpGet Request returns 'Undocumented Error:OK' on Swagger for no reason

Tags: json, asp.net-core, swagger, httprequest

The problematic api is implemented on my controller.cs as such:

```
    [HttpGet("GetAlarmList")]
    public IActionResult GetAlarmList()
    {
        try
        {
            ICollection<Alarm> alarms = repo.GetAlarmList();
            return Ok(alarms);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

You can assume that alarms have the correct value right before returning.
The 'Alarm' class is defined as below:

```
public class Alarm
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AlarmId { get; set; }
    public string FaultType { get; set; }
    public int DateOccurred { get; set; }
    public Sensor Sensor { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentType { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SettingId")]
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
}
```

However, swagger returns an error for no specific reason as the screenshot attached.
[image]

Can anyone spot a problem here?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the repo constructor.

```
 public class DataManagerRepository
    {
        private readonly PDAContext _context;

        public SensorsRepository SensorRepo;
        //IDataManager datmanager;
        public DataManagerRepository(PDAContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            SensorRepo = new SensorsRepository(context);

            String filepath = "C:\\projects\\Corona\\Sec_Files\\";

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.dat");

            int numfiles = files.Length;
            if (_context.Settings.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.Settings.Add(new Setting { });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            var setting = _context.Settings.FirstOrDefault();

            ICollection<PD_Datafile> PD_Datafiles = new Collection<PD_Datafile>();

            var rd = new Random();

            ICollection<PD_Datafile> pdfiles = new Collection<PD_Datafile>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numfiles; i++)
            {
                DAT_FILE PD_Datafile = ParseFileName(files[i].Name, filepath);
                string databodystr = Encoding.Default.GetString(PD_Datafile.SensorData.DataBody);
                PD_Datafiles.Add(new PD_Datafile() {FullName = files[i].Name, DataBody = databodystr });
                
            }
            setting.PD_Datafiles = PD_Datafiles;

            _context.SaveChanges();
            
            
            if (_context.Alarms.ToList().Count == 0)
            {
                ICollection<Alarm> alarms = new Collection<Alarm>();
                _context.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { DateOccurred = 202101201200, EquipmentType = "GISPD", FaultType = "PD Happening", Sensor = null, Details = "None" });
                _context.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { DateOccurred = 202101211210, EquipmentType = "CBCM", FaultType = "Warning", Sensor = null, Details = "None" });
                _context.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { DateOccurred = 202101221340, EquipmentType = "DGA", FaultType = "Danger", Sensor = null, Details = "None" });
                _context.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { DateOccurred = 202101230635, EquipmentType = "OLTC", FaultType = "Danger", Sensor = null, Details = "None" });
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Data Manager Initialized!");
        }
```

Comment: HI@Taki , can you provide your `repo` code ?

Comment: Hey @XinranShen. I've just updated the edit.

Comment: Are there any error messages on the "Console" tab of the browser dev tools when you execute the request?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem and here is my solution.

The problem was not in the controller code, but in the middleware, where the `next()` delegate was called several times. Check if you have a similar problem with your middleware. Here is an example:

**Incorrect code:**

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (true)
    {
        // some code...
        await _next(context);
        // some code...
    }

    await _next(context);
}
```

**Possible solution:**

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    if (true)
    {
        // some code...
        await _next(context);
        // some code...
    }
    else
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```